Indexing folder content by alphabetical order in Excel
So, I manage to index files from folders with the following formula :
=IFERROR(INDEX(E_Standard,ROW()-1),"")
Where "E_Standard" is a Name for =FILES(Standard!$A$2) and in cell "Standard!$A$2" you have my folder path : "N:\\Guitar stuff\\Vids\\Doable\\Standard\\E Standard\\Redone\*".
All of this were fine until now, because for some reasons, the alphabetical order is now not respected (as seen in the screenshot below).

All the other tabs works fine but none of them approach the number of files this one does (114 for the second with the most files, while this one is at 648)
Could it be any reason to why it doesn't list it in alphabetical order anymore ?

I tried to clean the tab and put the formula again, it didn't change anything. I expected some problem with the auto-refresh

I tried to reload the folder's content, no effect either, I expected some problem on the first reload of the folder


How I'd like it to be in the end

What is FILES() here =FILES(Standard!$A$2)? Is it a custom function?

The odds are everything is sorted correctly based on some hidden/unprintable characters. There is no reason for a function not to work correctly when  sorting a list.

INDEX(E_Standard,ROW()-1) with ROW()=1 will simply return all rows in the array returned by E_Standard and a single row otherwise. To get get results sorted, why not use SORT(IFERROR(E_Standard,""))?

You could also try using PowerQuery with Folder.Files(path) and Table.Sort and see whether results get sorted as expected.

@Harun24hr : FILES() is a simple function, but I think you need to enable the macros in the trust center for this one to be enabled.

@nkalvi : I don't have access to INDEX nor FILTER functions, seems to be a part of Office Insider (I just did a quick google search)
I am not really use to PowerQuery, I ll look into that

@Dasheng, could you please provide the Excel version you're using? SORT may be available. Using Power Query does not require saving workbook as macro-enabled - so I usually prefer it. I could post a suggestion if you would like.

@nkalvi I use Home and Student 2016, and if I recall correctly, a 32-bits version (I know it caused me some troubles at some point)

Thanks for the info @Dasheng, I'll see whether I can suggest a way.

It is either related to your data, or to the code in your FILES function. If you post the latter, some help may be available.

For Multiple Paths
2024-09-22
Paths could be in a single column or row.

In Excel, select the range containing the folder paths and define a name (Formulas > Define Name); in the example I used folderPaths - range containing the paths need
Create a blank query: Power Query from menu bar > From Other Sources > Blank Query
Click on Advanced Editor and enter code below

let
  fxFileNames = (path) =>
    let
      Source      = Folder.Contents(path), 
      keepNameCol = Table.SelectColumns(Source, {"Name"}), 
      nameList    = Table.ToList(keepNameCol)
    in
      nameList, 

  fxExpandAll = (t as table, optional colNum as number) =>
    let
      colNames = Table.ColumnNames(t), 
      Index    = if colNum = null then 0 else colNum, 
      expand   = Table.ExpandListColumn(t, colNames{Index}), 
      nextCol  = Index + 1, 
      repeat   = if nextCol < List.Count(colNames) then @fxExpandAll(expand, nextCol) else expand
    in
      repeat, 

  paths = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name = "folderPaths"]}[Content],
  pathsAsCols = if Table.RowCount(paths) > 1 then Table.Transpose(paths) else paths,
  colNames = Table.ColumnNames(pathsAsCols), 
  nameListInCols = Table.TransformColumns(
    pathsAsCols, 
    List.Transform(colNames, (col) => {col, each fxFileNames(_)})
  ), 
  expandAll = fxExpandAll(nameListInCols)

in
  expandAll


Rename the query as for example getFileNamesInColumns
Click Done and then Close & Load

Please refresh when you update the paths or the range (from Query > Refresh)
I have used Ron's recursive function for expanding columns.

Get File Names with Power Query in Excel 2016

Install Power Query from Download Microsoft Power Query for Excel from Official Microsoft Download Center
In Excel, select the cell containing the folder path and define a name (Formulas > Define Name); in the example I used folderPath
Create a blank query: Power Query from menu bar > From Other Sources > Blank Query
Click on Advanced Editor and enter code below

let
  path        = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name = "folderPath"]}[Content]{0}[Column1],
  Source      = Folder.Contents(path),
  keepNameCol = Table.SelectColumns(Source, {"Name"}),
  sortedNames = Table.Sort(keepNameCol, {{"Name", Order.Ascending}})
in
  sortedNames


Click Done and then Close & Load

See the whether names are sorted as exepected.
Results from Power Query need to be manually refreshed whenever there's a change (either to the folder path or to the contents of the folder.)

This is totally working, it sort it the right way thank you.
Is there a way I could have multiple column in one query ? I tried by myself and I don't really manage to do that. The multiple columns (6 of them) would all be the same thing but for different folders (folderPath1, folderPath2, etc.)

Excel loads every songs, but they appear all in one column. Is there anything in the code that I needed to customize for it to work ?
Outside the advanced editor, I can see that the "nameListInCols" is just "list" 10 times inside "Column 1". "colNames" is also only "Column 1".
My paths contains space, if I wasn't supposed to customize the code, could this be the problem ? If so, the name of each column is whatever is after the last "", maybe it could help knowing that

@Dasheng, I've updated code to handle paths given in a single column or row. Please test it when you get a chance.
